# Random.nextInt returns contiguous same-value integers (frequently)

Tags: java, scala, random, statistics

I see results like the below when running `scala.util.Random().nextInt(3)` 81 times (Java developers, please see `edit` for how this relates):

`200010202002112102222211012021020111220022001021101222222022210222220100000100010`

Notice the large contiguous blocks:
`000`, `22222`, `111`, `222222`, `222`, `22222`, `00000`, `000`.

Intuitively, the sequence doesn't seem naturally / "real-world coin flip" random.

For example, to achieve `6x` contiguous `2`s there's only a `0.4%` chance  (AFAIK) and for `5x` contiguous values there's a `1.2%` chance ... so it seems unlikely I should keep seeing patterns like this in the output.

Would this happen in the real-world with a 3-sided coin? Or is this an expected deviation from "true random" when using Java's `Random.nextInt(exclusiveMax)` method?

**EDIT:**

I've actually been using `scala.util.Random.nextInt(int)`, which  creates a new global `java.util.Random` via `new java.util.Random()`.

Comment: We cannot help you with code we cannot see. There is no `Random.nextInt(int)`, so the only code in the question clearly isn't your actual code (`nextInt` is an instance method, not a class method). Please add a [mcve] demonstrating the problem. Most likely, you're creating the `Random` instance with the same seed. Remember that `Random` produces the same sequence if you start with the same seed, that's why it's a *psuedo*-random number generator.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thank you, clarification has been added.

Comment: Using your sample output, out of 81 values after the first, 47 are different to the previous one and 33 are the same. That doesn't seem *wildly* wrong to me. (In a perfect world you'd get 33%.) With a small sample size, it's believable. If you got the same proportion after hundreds of thousands of results, I'd be more worried.

Comment: @JonSkeet following the test you suggested, I am seeing 33.33% with a larger sample size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a joke: I'd try it in the real world (probably easiest with two coins: Both heads = 0, mixed = 1, both tails = 2). I suspect you'll see the same result.

You only have three values, so the chances of something being a 2 are always 1:3. You're quite right that, having got a 2, your odds of getting 2 five more times in a row are about 0.04%, which is indeed unlikely in 81 rolls. But after getting a 2, your odds of getting *four* more are (as you say) 1.23% — much more likely, and not surprising in 81 rolls.

Running the program below myself, I routinely get runs of three in an 81-roll batch and frequently get runs of four, but only rarely runs of five, and *quite* rarely runs of six. All of which largely matches my expectation.

[Measuring the randomness of a PRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness_tests) is a quite complicated topic. The simplistic measure is to run it millions of times and then see if you've gotten each value ~0.33333333% of the time. But of course, that could be a million 0s followed by a million 1s followed by a million 2s, which would be a suspicious random result. :-) But you could try several of the approaches discussed in that Wikipedia article if you want to test your setup. Or subscribe to sources of true randomness like https://www.random.org/. Or a random USB device (though I'd subject one of those to quite a lot of due diligence).

My program:

```
import java.util.*;

public class E {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random r = new Random();
        Map<Integer,Integer> runs = new TreeMap<>();
        int last = -1;
        int run = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 81; ++i) {
            int v = r.nextInt(3);
            if (v != last) {
                if (i != 0) {
                    if (runs.containsKey(run)) {
                        runs.put(run, runs.get(run) + 1);
                    } else {
                        runs.put(run, 1);
                    }
                    System.out.println(" (" + run + ")");
                }
                last = v;
                run = 0;
            }
            ++run;
            System.out.print(v);
        }
        System.out.println("\n****");
        for (Map.Entry e : runs.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(e.getKey() + ": " + e.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That's my Sunday afternoon sorted :)

Comment: @LawrenceWagerfield: LOL